# How do I combine two input variables into one line?

Tags: java

The given problem is to be able to input 2 digits in one line, instead of:

```
Input:
2
2

Output:
1
```

It should be:

```
Input:
2 2

Output:
1
```

To make more sense, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = input.nextInt();
    
    int sum = a % b;
    
    System.out.print(sum);
    
    input.close();
  }
}
```

I want a code that only requires you to input two digits in one line instead of having to input the 2 digits separately.

Comment: Btw, you shouldnt close scanners tied to System.in. It is not your responsibility (but the JVMs) to close System.in. This can lead to bugs (for example a second scanner not being able to read anymore).

Comment: Zabuzard is right. The rule of thumb here is "don't close what you didn't open". The JVM opened stdin, so the JVM should close it (and it does).

Answer (score 0):

You can use one string input. Take this string and split it by whitespace then parse it by int.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    var str = input.nextLine();
   
    var delimeter = " "; 
    var subStr = str.split(delimeter); 
    var nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < subStr.length; i++) 
    { 
        nums.add(Integer.parseInt(subStr[i]));
    }
    
    var sum = nums.get(0) % nums.get(1);
    System.out.println(sum);
    
    input.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please demonstrate.

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scanner inside another scanner like below and iterate it to get values
To sum you can you collectors.summingInt()
working sample:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Summing {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

 
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(scanner.nextLine());
 
            while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                tokens.add(lineScanner.next());
            }
 
            lineScanner.close();
            
            System.out.println(tokens.stream()
            .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
            .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue)));
        }
 
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: sample intput and output is                                                                                                       intput -> 1 2,
output -> 3
intput -> 2 3
output -> 5